# Tokenize vector of dataframe by word

Tags: r

Im trying to tokenize by word the `email` column of df dataset but I get

```
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

df<-structure(list(email = c("' date wed NUMBER aug NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER from chris garrigues cwg dated NUMBER NUMBERfaNUMBERd deepeddy com message id NUMBER NUMBER tmda deepeddy vircio com i can t reproduce this error for me it is very repeatable like every time without fail this is the debug log of the pick happening NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER pick_it exec pick inbox list lbrace lbrace subject ftp rbrace rbrace NUMBER NUMBER sequence mercury NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER exec pick inbox list lbrace lbrace subject ftp rbrace rbrace NUMBER NUMBER sequence mercury NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER ftoc_pickmsgs NUMBER hit NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER marking NUMBER hits NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER tkerror syntax error in expression int note if i run the pick command by hand delta pick inbox list lbrace lbrace subject ftp rbrace rbrace NUMBER NUMBER sequence mercury NUMBER hit that s where the NUMBER hit comes from obviously the version of nmh i m using is delta pick version pick nmh NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER compiled on URL at sun mar NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER ict NUMBER and the relevant part of my mh_profile delta mhparam pick seq sel list since the pick command works the sequence actually both of them the one that s explicit on the command line from the search popup and the one that comes from mh_profile do get created kre ps this is still using the version of the code form a day ago i haven t been able to reach the cvs repository today local routing issue i think _______________________________________________ exmh workers mailing list exmh workers URL URL '", 
                             "'martin a posted tassos papadopoulos the greek sculptor behind the plan judged that the limestone of mount kerdylio NUMBER miles east of salonika and not far from the mount athos monastic community was ideal for the patriotic sculpture as well as alexander s granite features NUMBER ft high and NUMBER ft wide a museum a restored amphitheatre and car park for admiring crowds are planned so is this mountain limestone or granite if it s limestone it ll weather pretty fast yahoo groups sponsor NUMBER dvds free s p join now URL to unsubscribe from this group send an email to forteana unsubscribe URL your use of yahoo groups is subject to URL '"
), label = c("0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                           "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                                                             email = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                 "collector")), label = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)

ab <- data.frame(df$email) %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)

library(tidyr)

bigrams_separated <- ab %>%
  separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument to `unnest_tokens` is the input i.e the column in the dataframe which needs to be split. You have passed it as `text` but there is no `text` column in your data.

You can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, email, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
  separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
  select(-label) -> bigrams_separated

bigrams_separated

# A tibble: 368 x 2
#   word1  word2 
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 date   wed   
# 2 wed    number
# 3 number aug   
# 4 aug    number
# 5 number number
# 6 number number
# 7 number number
# 8 number number
# 9 number from  
#10 from   chris 
# … with 358 more rows
```